# SQL: Order By, Substring, Union

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I wish to order the results of the below query by a substring of the first 8 characters of the 'version' number. I understand SUBSTRING(), so don't bother me with that. My problem is trying to actually place the ORDER BY in regards to the UNION.

UPDATE:  I need the data returned in order of Version, but still also ordered next to other rows with the same GUID.

The current query is like this, but versions come in random order.

```
/**** PLAYER MATCHUPS TWO  ***/    
SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE]    
FROM db e INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT[GUID] FROM db
    WHERE[Key] = 'Session.Type' and[Value] = 'EndMatchTypA') g 
ON e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
WHERE [KEY] IN('CharacterID', 
            'OpponentID', 
            'Version')
UNION ALL

/**** PLAYER MATCHUPS ONE  ***/
SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT[GUID] FROM db
    WHERE[Key] = 'Session.Type' and [Value] = 'EndMatchTypeB') g 
ON e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
WHERE[KEY] IN('CharacterID', 
        'OpponentID',
        'Version')
```

This is how the data returns at the moment.

```
GUID        Key             Value
-------------------------------------------
1313-2212   Version         3.0.4.0_x64_!#
1313-2212   CharacterID     3
1313-2212   OpponentID      5
4321-1567   Version         1.0.0.0_x64_!#
4321-1567   CharacterID     11
4321-1567   OpponentID      2
```

Comment: Which column do you want to `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: all the keys need to be ordered by the "value" of the version Key (e.g. 1.0.0.0 > 1.2.0.0 > 2.0.0.0 >3.0.0.0), but still bundled together by the GUID.

Comment: IIRC you should be OK to put the `ORDER BY` *after* the last `WHERE`; it will order both of the `UNION`-ed queries. Alternatively, to make this more explicit, you could turn the entire query into a subquery or use a CTE. However, you might find it tricky to get the ordering you want based on the string values in your data. I would tend to favour doing that in my client or middle tier. SQL's string manipulation is limited; you also negate the benefit of any index on the version values by ordering by a function.

Comment: @MichaelMeritt, I think `'appVer'` should be `'Version'` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @MichaelMeritt But what will happen if one of the version digits by two wide, e.g. `1.10.0.0`.  In this case, you would want the first _nine_ characters, right?  Can you show us the general format for a version string?

Comment: heh. Very good gotcha. Our versions wont climb that high, but yes. this would cause issues.

Comment: I won't cause issues if the version always end with an underscore (`_`), for example.  Please show us the general format for a version string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do another `JOIN` to the `db` table to get the `Version` for each `[KEY]` sort by that:

```
SELECT 
    e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e 
INNER JOIN db g 
    ON  e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
        AND g.[Key] = 'Session.Type'
        AND g.[Value] IN ('EndMatchTypeA', 'EndMatchTypeB')
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [GUID], [KEY], [VALUE]
    FROM db
    WHERE
        [KEY] = 'Version'
)v
    ON e.[GUID] = v.[GUID]
WHERE 
    e.[KEY] IN ('CharacterID', 'OpponentID', 'Version')
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(v.[VALUE], 1, 8);
```

---

You can also use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT 
    e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e 
INNER JOIN db g 
    ON  e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
        AND g.[Key] = 'Session.Type'
        AND g.[Value] IN ('EndMatchTypeA', 'EndMatchTypeB')
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT [GUID], [KEY], [VALUE]
    FROM db
    WHERE
        [KEY] = 'Version'
        AND [GUID] = e.[GUID]
)v
WHERE 
    e.[KEY] IN ('CharacterID', 'OpponentID', 'Version')
ORDER BY 
    SUBSTRING(v.[VALUE], 1, 8);
```

*Credits to Gordon for getting rid of the `UNION ALL`.*

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the entire query and then `SELECT` from it using `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT t.[GUID], t.[KEY], t.[VALUE]
FROM
(
    SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE]    
    FROM db e INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT[GUID] FROM db
        WHERE[Key] = 'Session.Type' and[Value] = 'EndMatchTypA') g 
    ON e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
    WHERE [KEY] IN('CharacterID', 
                'OpponentID', 
                'appVer')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
    FROM db e INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT[GUID] FROM db
        WHERE[Key] = 'Session.Type' and [Value] = 'EndMatchTypeB') g 
    ON e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] 
    WHERE[KEY] IN('CharacterID', 
            'OpponentID',
            'appVer')
) t
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(t.[VALUE], 1, 8)
```

Note: I tested ordering string version numbers, and the numerical order appears to remain intact.  However, you should be aware that if your version number length should change, this could be a problem.  For example, if versions could become two digits, this would break the `ORDER BY` I gave (as well as given by the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

The query can be simplified as below. Use `substring` to get the first 8 characters of `value` and replace the `.` characters with empty character so it can be ordered as an integer.

```
SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT[GUID] FROM db
 WHERE [Key] = 'Session.Type' and [Value] = 'EndMatchTypeA') ga
ON e.[GUID] = ga.[GUID] 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT[GUID] FROM db
 WHERE [Key] = 'Session.Type' and [Value] = 'EndMatchTypeB') gb
ON e.[GUID] = gb.[GUID] 
WHERE e.[KEY] IN ('CharacterID','OpponentID','appVer')
ORDER BY cast(replace(substring(e.[VALUE],1,8),'.','') as int)
```

If you want to use `order by` with `union`, use `order by` at the end of the `union` query.

```
select col1,col2 from sometable --where conditions
union all
select col1,col2 from sometable1 --where conditions
order by col1,col2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see why you need `union all`:

```
SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e INNER JOIN
     db g 
     ON e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] AND 
        g.[Key] = 'Session.Type' AND
        g.[Value] IN ('EndMatchTypeA', 'EndMatchTypeB') 
WHERE e.[KEY] IN ('CharacterID', 'OpponentID', 'Version')
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(e.[VALUE], 1, 8);
```

Then, I might change this to an `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.[GUID], e.[KEY], e.[VALUE] 
FROM db e 
WHERE e.[KEY] IN ('CharacterID', 'OpponentID', 'Version') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM db g 
              WHERE e.[GUID] = g.[GUID] AND 
                    g.[Key] = 'Session.Type' AND
                    g.[Value] IN ('EndMatchTypeA', 'EndMatchTypeB')
             )
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(e.[VALUE], 1, 8);
```

I think this best conveys the intent of the query.  And, it prevents duplicates in can `g` has both values.  And, it probably makes it easier for the optimizer to take advantage of appropriate indexes.